# Why does inspect.getargspec() return unsized objects?

Tags: python

I was working with the inspect module and noticed that it returned unsized objects from time to time. For example `inspect.getargspec(func)[3]` which returns the tuple? of the default values of the functions arguments. When you use `len()` on the previous snippet you get a cannot get the length of an unsized object.

Why is this an unsized object?

Comment: It should also be noted that [`inspect.getargspec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getargspec) is deprecated as of Python 3.0.  New code should use [`inspect.getfullargspec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getfullargspec).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> def f(x, y=1, z=2, *args, **kwargs): pass
>>> getargspec(f)
ArgSpec(args=['x', 'y', 'z'], varargs='args', keywords='kwargs', defaults=(1, 2))

>>> def g(x, y, z): pass
>>> getargspec(g)
ArgSpec(args=['x', 'y', 'z'], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=None)
```

If there are no defaults then the defaults value is None rather than an empty tuple.

If you need to test for presence of default arguments then rather than using `len`, just use the object itself.

eg.

```
if getargspec(g)[3]:
    ...
```

or better yet:

```
if getargspec(g).defaults:
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do

```
import inspect
def f(a,b,c,*d): pass

a = inspect.getargspec(f)
```

you get a result which is like

```
ArgSpec(args=['a', 'b', 'c'], varargs='d', keywords=None, defaults=None)
```

What does that man? It is an object which obviouusly has a length (`len(a) = 4`), and whose `[3]` I can get:

```
>>> a[3]
>>>
```

Huh? What's that?

```
>>> repr(a[3])
'None'
>>>
```

Ah, it is `None`. Ok.

Let's have another look:

```
>>> list(a)
[['a', 'b', 'c'], 'd', None, None]
```

It seems a `ArgSpec` object is something like a namedtuple; its `[3]` is the `defaults` value, which is just `None`.

It completely depends on what you try to do with that object.